# Linear Algebra Vector Space matrix help

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces, transformation

Let $M_{2\times2}$ be a vector space of all $2\times2$ matrices. If the transformation from $M_{2\times2}$ to $M_{2\times2}$ is $t(A)=A+A^T$ and $A$ is a $2\times2$ matrix with the top row $a,b$ and bottom row $c,d$.

Would the kernel of transformation $t$ be $0$? I keep getting $0$ since if I row reduce the transformation with plugged in numbers i keep getting $x1=0$ and $x2=0$.

Also, how do I show that the range of $t$  is the set of symmetric matrices? I know that means I am trying to find the set of $Q\in M_{2\times2}$ so that $Q^T=Q$

Lastly, would any matrix in the form of A mentioned in the beginning of the question be transformed into a matrix that is equal to its transpose. Whatever numbers I put in for matrix A, my transformed matrices are always equal to their respective transposes.

Answer (score 2):

Let's say more about this linear transformation.

First $$A\in \ker t\iff t(A)=A+A^T=0\iff A^T=-A\iff A\in\mathcal{AS_n}(\Bbb R)$$
hence $0$ is an eigenvalue of $t$ with multiplicity equal to 
$$\dim\mathcal{AS_n}(\Bbb R)=\frac{n(n-1)}2:=\alpha_n$$
and if $A\in\mathcal{M_n}(\Bbb R)$ then
$$t(A)=A+A^T\in\mathcal{S_n}(\Bbb R)$$
and by the rank-nullity theorem we have
$$\dim \operatorname{im}(t)=\dim\mathcal{M_n}(\Bbb R)-\dim\ker(t)=\dim\mathcal{S_n}(\Bbb R)$$
hence 
$$\operatorname{im}(t)=\mathcal{S_n}(\Bbb R)$$

moreover, if $A\in\mathcal{S_n}(\Bbb R)$ then 
$$t(A)=A+A^T=2A$$
hence $2$ is an eigenvalue of $t$ with multiplicity equal to
$$\dim\mathcal{S_n}(\Bbb R)=\frac{n(n+1)}2:=\beta_n$$
hence $t$ is diagonalizable and it's minimal polynomial is
$$\pi_t(x)=x(x-2)$$
and it's characteristic polynomial is
$$\chi_t(x)=x^{\alpha_n}(x-2)^{\beta_n}$$

Comment: Excellent descriptive and informative summary, Sami!

Answer (score 0):

The set of anti-symmetric $2\times2$ matrices, is the kernel of $t$:since if $A=-A^T$, then

$$t(A)=0$$

Answer (score 0):

No, the kernel is not zero: There are matrices such that $A^T = -A$, called *skew-symmetric*. Try a matrix with zeros on the main diagonal.

---

To show that the range of $t$ is the collection of symmetric matrices, you need to check two things:

- For any $A$, $t(A) =  A + A^T$ is symmetric.
- For any matrix $Q$ for which $Q^T = Q$, there is a matrix $A$ such that $A + A^T = Q$. After noting that
  $$Q = Q^T = (A + A^T)^T = A + A^T$$
  try something like $\frac 1 2 Q$.

---

Once you've finished the previous section, you should see that every possible output of $t$ is symmetric, so equal to its own transpose.

Comment: so is the kernel not 0? You said it isn't zero but Alt says it is

Comment: Alt said that the kernel is the set of anti-symmetric matrices (which is also what I said).

Comment: ok, also I was looking at your answer to show the range is a set of symmetric matrices. Is there a way to show this by having a matrix and setting it to 0 and reducing it to echelon form?

Comment: Reducing to echelon form won't help in finding the range (I'm also not sure what you mean by 'having a matrix and setting it to 0').

Comment: I meant solving for the kernel. Do I have to solve for the general solution? because when I solve for the kernel I get x1{1,0}+x2{0,1}

Comment: @user123204 I'm not sure what you mean; the kernel consists of the set of matrices such that $$\left[\begin{array}{cc} a & b \\ c & d\end{array}\right] = \left[\begin{array}{cc} -a & -c \\ -b & -d\end{array}\right]$$ So by inspection, $a = d = 0$, and $b = -c$.

Comment: http://www.math.lsa.umich.edu/~hochster/419/ker.im.html Here they described that to solve for a kernel, I must express the solution as a set of linear combinations

Comment: @user123204 The link is about finding the kernel of a *matrix* viewed as a linear transformation. This is a different case.